# CycleDOM conditional rendering issue

Tags: javascript, cyclejs

I'm having an issue with conditional rendering.
Here's my 100% working view:

```
function todoItem(todo) {
  return li('.list-item',[
    todo.editing ? input('.todo-edit', {type: 'text', value: todo.text, autofocus: true, attributes: { 'data-id': todo.id }}) : '',
    !todo.editing ? span(`.todo ${todo.completed ? '.completed' : ''}`, { attributes: { 'data-id': todo.id }}, todo.text) : '',
    button('.remove-todo', {type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'remove'),
    todo.completed ? button('.unmark-todo', {type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'unmark') : '',
    !todo.completed ? button('.mark-todo', {type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'mark as done') : ''
  ]);

const view = (state$) => {
  return state$.map(todos =>
    div([
      input('.todo-input', {type: 'text', placeholder: 'Todo', value: ''}),
      ul(todos.items.map(todo => todoItem(todo))),
      footer(todos)
    ])
  );
};
```

The problem is when I try to change the conditional buttons to an if-else instead of two separate conditions:

```
todo.completed ?
  button('.unmark-todo', {type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'unmark') : 
  button('.mark-todo', {type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'mark as done')
```

It seems that it toggles the button to "unmark" then back to "mark" again (i've confirmed that with console logs). My intents are mapped to those two classes **.mark** and **.unmark**, so I don't think that's an issue...

Is that an actual error or am I missing something?

Comment: create a filled or http://webpackbin.com

Comment: That is probably this bug: https://github.com/cyclejs/core/issues/228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering this bug in the dom driver: https://github.com/cyclejs/core/issues/228

The "problem" is that both the elements you are toggling are buttons. So when switching from `todo.completed` to `!todo.completed` virtual-dom will not create a new button but just update the class and the label of the old button (because you want minimal dom changes).

This does happen synchronously while the click event is being still processed. After the class name is updated the event will be processed by the next listener which is now also matching the (new) class name and accepts the event as well. This second listener is the one that will unmark the task again.

The quick fix for you is to give both buttons a `key` attribute to force virtual-dom to recreated the button. But as I said it's a bug in the dom driver.

```
todo.completed ?
  button('.unmark-todo', {key: 'unmark', type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'unmark') : 
  button('.mark-todo', {key: 'mark', type: 'button', value: todo.id}, 'mark as done')
```

Comment: Hmm I see! Thank you for the help :)